# Can CAShapeLayer shapes center itself in a subView?

Tags: swift, cashapelayer, caanimation

I created an arbitrary view

```swift
let middleView = UIView(
    frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,
                  y: view.frame.height/4,
                  width: view.frame.width,
                  height: view.frame.height/4))
middleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
view.addSubview(middleView)
```

Then I created a circle using UIBezierPath; however when I set the position to middleView.center, the circle is far off to the bottom of the view. Can you set the position in the center of a subview?

[image: iPhone 8 Plus with view and uncentered circle]

```swift
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(
        arcCenter: .zero,
        radius: 100,
        startAngle: CGFloat(0).toRadians(),
        endAngle: CGFloat(360).toRadians(),
        clockwise: true)
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
shapeLayer.position = middleView.center
middleView.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

How do I center this circle in that view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you are setting `shapeLayer.position = middleView.center`. The `center` of a view is is the superview's geometry. In other words, `middleView.center` is relative to `view`, not to `middleView`. But then you're adding `shapeLayer` as a sublayer of `middleView.layer`, which means `shapeLayer` needs a `position` that is in `middleView`'s geometry, not in `view`'s geometry. You need to set `shapeLayer.position` to the center of `middleView.bounds`:

```
shapeLayer.position = CGPoint(x: middleView.bounds.midX, y: middleView.bounds.midY)
```

Second, you didn't say where you're doing all this. My guess is you're doing it in `viewDidLoad`. But that is too early. In `viewDidLoad`, the views loaded from the storyboard still have the frames they were given in the storyboard, and haven't been laid out for the current device's screen size yet. So it's a bad idea to look at `frame` (or `bounds` or `center`) in `viewDidLoad` if you don't do something to make sure that things will be laid out correctly during the layout phase. Usually you do this by setting the `autoresizingMask` or creating constraints. Example:

```
let middleView = UIView(
    frame: CGRect(x: 0.0,
                  y: view.frame.height/4,
                  width: view.frame.width,
                  height: view.frame.height/4))
middleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
middleView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
view.addSubview(middleView)
```

However, `shapeLayer` doesn't belong to a view, so it doesn't have an `autoresizingMask` and can't be constrained. You have to lay it out in code. You could do that, but it's better to just use a view to manage the shape layer. That way, you can use `autoresizingMask` or constraints to control the layout of the shape, and you can set it up in `viewDidLoad`.

```
    let circleView = CircleView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
    circleView.center = CGPoint(x: middleView.bounds.midX, y: middleView.bounds.midY)
    circleView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin]
    circleView.shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    circleView.shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
    middleView.addSubview(circleView)

...

class CircleView: UIView {
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CAShapeLayer.self }

    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { return layer as! CAShapeLayer }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).cgPath
    }

}
```

Result:

[image: demo]

And after rotating to landscape:

[image: demo in landscape]

Comment: thanks! this was very insightful. One Q: can I switch out `circleView.autoresizingMask = [...]` for autolayout constraints? are they performing the same task?

Comment: Yes, you can use constraints to lay out `circleView` if you remember to set `circleVIew.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

Comment: I guess, im confused how the `0` in `CGRect.x` and `CGRect.y` is allowing the circle to be centered

Comment: Those don’t matter because I set `circleView.center` on the next line.